# Set the grid container div width by the width of one of it's rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input"></div>
  <div class="filter buttons"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

And this is their styling:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
    padding: 30px 15px;
}

.input {
    max-width: 350px;
}

.filter-buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, 170px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

You can see the [codesanbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-brown-mh48q?file=/index.html). What I would like is to have the container width set by the width of the row with filter buttons. I can't have it fixed, since filter buttons have auto wrapping set with `auto-fit`. And since content takes the full width, the containers width is set by the content width. 
What I am trying to achieve is to have a responsive layout with css grid and without having to use media queries, where container would follow the width of `filter_buttons` div.
So, it would look like this on the small screens:

[image]

And like this on bigger screens:

[image]
How can I achieve that kind of layout?

Comment: `width: 0;
    min-width: 100%` to the content div ?

Comment: but, then the buttons are not taking the space they could otherwise

Comment: share a screenshot to better explain what you want

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshots of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: What you need is probably : `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(170px , 1fr));` for `.filter-buttons` ?? https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-resonance-84g1x

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Perfect, that is it! Thank you very much!